# How to detect Collision Between two UIImageViews belonging in two different UIViews?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, collision-detection, collision

I am noob in Iphone programming, so please help.

I am rotating 2 Views in opposite direction in circular way. Now I want to find out when both images are intersected.

As of now I am rotating view not Image so CGRectIntersectsRect() won't give me the desired result. Is there any other way I can get the solution i.e. intersection of both images ?

My problem is both are in different views. Any idea or suggestion or code snippet would be great to work further towards my goal.

--Edited--
I have 2 views in one view 1st image in another 2nd image. I am rotating both views in different direction circular. there will be one time when both image will be at same location. I am unable to use CGRectIntersectsRect() as both are in different views.

How do I know that both image met at location ? i.e. Collision occurred. Please forgive abt not providing clear explanation about question.

Comment: Not very clear about the question. Assuming it is caused as the two images are in difference coordination. So try getting the two images' rect coordinations in a common parent view and use CGRectIntersectsRect() to detect intersection.

Comment: @Tony_Wu : I have 2 views in one view 1st image in another 2nd image. I am rotating both views in different direction circular. there will be one time when both image will be at same location. I am unable to use CGRectIntersectsRect() as both are in different views.

How do I know that both image met at location ? i.e. Collision occurred. Please forgive abt not providing clear explanation about question.

Comment: @Tony_Wu: I tried it with no luck. Though thax any way for your help. My guess in this is I have Views size is larger than the window. like PlayerView(UIView) is (1,92,482,540) and PlayerImage(UIImage) in that is (187,0,90,15) to have proper round rotation on screen. Now if I use CGRect playerFrame = [playerImages convertRect:playerImages.frame toView:nil]; than I am geting (X,Y) as (112,16) which I don't understand. Once again Thax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method to convert the rect in the view to the rect in window coordinates, then use CGRectIntersectsRect() .  Hope this works for you.

> Converts a rectangle from the
>   receiver’s coordinate system to that
>   of another view.
>
> - (CGRect)convertRect:(CGRect)rect toView:(UIView *)view
>
> Parameters rect A rectangle in the
>   receiver's coordinate system. view The
>   view that is the target of the
>   conversion operation. If view is nil,
>   this method instead converts from
>   window base coordinates. Otherwise,
>   both view and the receiver must belong
>   to the same UIWindow object. Return
>   Value The converted rectangle.

Comment: I tried the method you suggested. Though it didn't work for me. Just let me show you the code i wrote and if ne mistake please point it out. > I have 2 UIViews (PlayerView and HurdleView containing playerImage and HurdleImage respectively). Both are of different size. while rotating them I wrote - "CGRect playerFrame = [playerImages convertRect:playerImages.frame toView:self.view]; CGRect hurdleFrame = [hurdleImg convertRect:playerImages.frame toView:self.view];" > I am getting both at different location in nslog but on screen both are at same location. Any hint ?

Comment: @Jennis You may try this:[playerImages convertRect:playerImages.frame toView:nil]. > If view is nil, this method instead converts from window base coordinates.